# Adding two complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

I have two complex numbers: $Z_1=e^{-j45°}$ and $Z_2=e^{j135°}$.

I need to calculate $2*Z_1+Z_2$.

I know how to do it when I convert with help of Eulers formula n form $\cos(x)+j\sin(x)$, but that is just too complicated to calculate.

Is there any easier way to do the given operation.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Are those supposed to be degrees signs?

Comment: $Z_1=-Z_2$ then it becomes easier. $e^{i135^{\circ}}=e^{-i45^{\circ}+i180^{\circ}}=e^{-i45^{\circ}}e^{i180^{\circ}}=-e^{-i45^{\circ}}$

Comment: @user92774 Yes, they are degree signs

Answer (score 1):

Hint #1: $2z_1+z_2=z_1+(z_1+z_2)$.

Hint #2: Plot $z_1$ and $z_2$ on the complex plane. Does their sum have an obvious "nice" value?

Answer (score 1):

$e^{-i45^\circ}$ is a complex number with angle $-45^\circ = 315^\circ$

$e^{i 135^\circ}$ is a complex number with angle $135^\circ$

What happens when you add two numbers whose angles differ by $180^\circ$?

Comment: I have no idea what will happend

Comment: It will add up to zero?

Comment: Well, it depends on the magnitude of each number. Think about it graphically in terms of vectors.